# Como modificar un elemento padre cuando el elemento hijo este en estado hover?

Tags: css, css3, selectores-css, selectores

Quiero realizar una animación (que aparezca una barra desde la izq); el elemento after esta sobre el padre de .content-tittle__tittle(cuando este elemento este en estado hover se tiene que realizar al animaccion).

Se que la solucion mas facil poner el width: 100% sobre el elemento padre --anim

Pero si hay una forma de lograr cambiar el width de --anim cuando "content-tittle__tittle" este en hover seria una gloria.

```css
.--anim::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out, left 0.5s ease-in-out; }

    /* .--anim:hover::after {
    width: 100%;} */


    .content-tittle__tittle:hover{
    .--anim::after & {
      width: 100%;} }
  

    .--animToLeft::after {
    left: 0;}
```

```html
 <section class="containerDT">
          <div class="content-tittle --anim --animToLeft">
            <h2 class="content-tittle__tittle">Actividades</h2>
            <h3 class="content-tittle__parroquia">Comunidad Centro</h3>
          </div>
    <section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usas el pseudo selector [has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), el cual te permite seleccionar un padre que tiene hijos que cumplan con el selector que se pasa como argumento

```css
#padre{
  background-color:red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  padding:10px;
}

#hijo{
  background-color:blue;
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
}

#padre:has(#hijo:hover){
  background-color:gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="padre">
 <div id="hijo"></div>
</div>
```

```
--anim.has(.content-tittle__tittle:hover){
  width: ...
}
```